# Python Update Value in one Line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python I have:

```
c_f = None
#c_f may change here
if not c_f:
    c_f = new_c_f
```

Can I write last 2 lines in one line?

1. If I want to keep **first** non-None value
2. If I want to keep **last** non-None value

Please Note that doing:

```
c_f = c_f or new_c_f
```

solves one of the cases

Comment: Just reverse the order to do 2. `c_f = new_c_f or c_f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to squish

```
if not c_f:
    c_f = new_c_f
```

to one line, you can change it to a one-liner:

```
if not c_f: c_f = new_c_f
```